# omnipay paypal express not returning address

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant, omnipay

I am using the omnipay setup here: https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay to process a paypal express checkout.

The process works fine in that the user is redirected to paypal -> they login and choose to pay -> they get returned to my site at which point I capture the payment.

The problem I've got is that I need to capture the address they have entered into paypal as their billing / shipping address.

To send the user across to paypal I have the following:

```
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setUsername('XX-USERNAME_XX');
$gateway->setPassword('XX_PASSWORDXX');
$gateway->setSignature('XX_SIG_XX');
$gateway->setTestMode(true);

$response = $gateway->purchase(
    array(
        'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.XXX.co.uk/',
        'returnUrl'=>'http://www.XXX.co.uk/paypalexpress_confirm',
        'amount' =>  $totalamount,
        'currency' => 'GBP'
    )
)->send();

$response->redirect();
```

When the user is returned I have the following:

```
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setUsername('XX-USERNAME_XX');
$gateway->setPassword('XX_PASSWORDXX');
$gateway->setSignature('XX_SIG_XX');
$gateway->setTestMode(true);

$response = $gateway->completePurchase(
    array(
        'cancelUrl'=>'http://www.XXX.co.uk/',
        'returnUrl'=>'http://www.XXX.co.uk/paypalexpress_confirm',
        'amount' =>  $totalamount,
        'currency' => 'GBP'
    )
    )->send();

    echo $responsemsg=$response->getMessage(); 

    echo '<br><br><br>';
    $data = $response->getData(); 
    print_r($data);
```

Nothing in the response message or the raw data contains the customer address.

Has anyone got this working as i'm struggling and it's the final step to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are trying to get this work it's as Adrian said.

You first do the normal omnipay paypal payment and then afterwards:

1. get the token you were given
2. preform a second call to paypal using the call getexpresscheckoutdetails method
3. this returns all the info you need

API info here: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails

The php script paypal provide to do it all for you:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/ES/es_ES/files/developer/nvp_ECGetExpressCheckout_php.txt

Answer (score 1):

`omnipay\paypal\ProGateway.php` add new function

```
public function fetchExpressCheckoutDetail(array $parameters = array())
{
    return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\PayPal\Message\FetchExpressCheckoutRequest', $parameters);
}
```

`omnipay\paypal\src\Message` add new file `FetchExpressCheckoutRequest.php`

```
namespace Omnipay\PayPal\Message;
class FetchExpressCheckoutRequest extends AbstractRequest
{
    public function getData()
    {
        $data = $this->getBaseData('GetExpressCheckoutDetails');

        $this->validate('transactionReference');
        $data['TOKEN'] = $this->getTransactionReference();
        $url = $this->getEndpoint()."?USER={$data['USER']}&PWD={$data['PWD']}&SIGNATURE={$data['SIGNATURE']}&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&VERSION={$data['VERSION']}&TOKEN={$data['TOKEN']}";
        parse_str (file_get_contents( $url ),$output);
        $data = array_merge($data,$output);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
$data = $response->getData();
$gateway->fetchExpressCheckoutDetail(array('transactionReference'=>$data['TOKEN']))->getData();
```

It will be not the best. But it works. :)

Comment: why are you using ProGateway.php file? Shouldn't it be ExpressGateway.php?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not returned by the `$response->getData()` method, you might need to call PayPal's `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` API method to get the extra details about the transaction.

Omnipay doesn't support this out of the box, so you will probably need to copy and customize one of the existing requests to make a separate API call after you have confirmed payment.

Comment: Ah right - can you point me in the right direction as to which file(s) I need to be looking at to make this adjustment? I'm struggling to see anything in the paypal folder that I can edit to include this?