# How to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails from Omnipay/PayPal?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, laravel-4, omnipay

I need to accept PayPal Express payments from a Laravel-4 app, so am trying to decide if Omnipay is the best solution.  The sticking point is that it doesn't seem to implement GetExpressCheckoutDetails, so the purchaser's contact details are not accessible. I've seen these discussions about the problem:

[omnipay paypal express not returning address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550467/omnipay-paypal-express-not-returning-address)

[receive more response data in ci-merchant library codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434555/receive-more-response-data-in-ci-merchant-library-codeigniter)

However, neither give a definitive solution.  If I use Omnipay, would I also have to install PayPal's Classic API (in which case, why bother with Omnipay), or can I implement GetExpressCheckoutDetails in Omnipay, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

`omnipay\paypal\ProGateway.php` add new function

```
public function fetchExpressCheckoutDetail(array $parameters = array())
{
    return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\PayPal\Message\FetchExpressCheckoutRequest', $parameters);
}
```

`omnipay\paypal\src\Message` add new file `FetchExpressCheckoutRequest.php`

```
namespace Omnipay\PayPal\Message;
class FetchExpressCheckoutRequest extends AbstractRequest
{
    public function getData()
    {
        $data = $this->getBaseData('GetExpressCheckoutDetails');

        $this->validate('transactionReference');
        $data['TOKEN'] = $this->getTransactionReference();
        $url = $this->getEndpoint()."?USER={$data['USER']}&PWD={$data['PWD']}&SIGNATURE={$data['SIGNATURE']}&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&VERSION={$data['VERSION']}&TOKEN={$data['TOKEN']}";
        parse_str (file_get_contents( $url ),$output);
        $data = array_merge($data,$output);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
$data = $response->getData();
$gateway->fetchExpressCheckoutDetail(array('transactionReference'=>$data['TOKEN']))->getData();
```

It will be not the best. But it works. :)

Comment: tomsowerby has implemented another solution in a pull request at this [link](https://github.com/omnipay/paypal/pull/18). It works, and I hope it's going to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

Omnipay doesn't support GetExpressCheckoutDetails (yet). There is a [pull request](https://github.com/omnipay/paypal/pull/11) currently open for this.

However it does implement [GetTransactionDetails](https://github.com/omnipay/paypal/blob/master/src/Message/FetchTransactionRequest.php) which you may find useful, as that can return most information about an existing transaction.

Comment: The pull request has been quiet for a couple of months. Any idea what the delay is?  I tried calling GetTransactionDetails via completePurchase, but it doesn't return the purchaser's contact details.

Comment: Just that it's a large pull request and I've been really busy so haven't had time to do the work myself. If it was broken up into separate PRs for GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and the API improved per the comments in that thread it would be fairly easy to merge.

Answer (score 0):

Based on kei. answer I suggest the following addition to the application:

1. Create new path `app/omnipay/paypal/Message/`
2. Create new file `app/omnipay/paypal/ExtendedExpressGateway.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Omnipay\PayPal;

   use Omnipay\PayPal\ExpressGateway;

   /**
    * PayPal Express extended Class
    */
   class ExtendedExpressGateway extends ExpressGateway
   {
       public function getName()
       {
           return 'PayPal Express extended';
       }

       public function fetchExpressCheckoutDetail(array $parameters = array())
       {
           return $this->createRequest('\\App\\Omnipay\\PayPal\\Message\\FetchExpressCheckoutRequest', $parameters);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create new file `app/omnipay/paypal/Message/FetchExpressCheckoutRequest.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Omnipay\PayPal\Message;

   use Omnipay\PayPal\Message\AbstractRequest;

   class FetchExpressCheckoutRequest extends AbstractRequest
   {
       public function getData()
       {
           $data = $this->getBaseData('GetExpressCheckoutDetails');

           $this->validate('transactionReference');

           $data['TOKEN'] = $this->getTransactionReference();
           $url = $this->getEndpoint() . "?USER={$data['USER']}&PWD={$data['PWD']}&SIGNATURE={$data['SIGNATURE']}&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&VERSION={$data['VERSION']}&TOKEN={$data['TOKEN']}";
           parse_str(file_get_contents($url), $output);
           $data = array_merge($data, $output);

           return $data;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add to `psr-4` `autoload` in composer.json

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           ...
       ],
       "psr-4": {
           "App\\Omnipay\\PayPal\\": "app/omnipay/paypal/"
       }
   },
   ```
5. run:

   ```
   php artisan dump-autoload
   ```
6. Now in `app/config/packages/ignited/laravel-omnipay/config.php` you can write:

   ```
   'driver' => '\\App\\Omnipay\\PayPal\\ExtendedExpressGateway',
   ```

Now when you update will be no problems

Comment: Warning: After implementing these steps and using "$gateway = new App\Omnipay\PayPal\ExtendedExpressGateway();" in place of "Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');" I found that ExtendedExpressGateway::fetchExpressCheckoutDetail() returned the same information as Omnipay's built-in "$data = $gateway->fetchCheckout($params)->send()->getData();” so it’s probably not worth the trouble.  Anyway, if you are having trouble with the psr-4 autoloader not finding ExtendedExpressGateway, remember to put "<?php" at the top of the php files!

Comment: Thanks @ZackMorris, this helped me a load and idealy should be the accepted best answer, please write a full reply so I can upvote it.

The benefit of using this method is that if the payer_id or the transaction_id were not saved, you only have the transaction reference id, this is the only way you can programatically get those details.